# Error converting varchar to bigint (CONVERT, SUBSTRING, PATINDEX)

Tags: sql-server

In the following sproc I'm having troubles converting my id into a bigint when returning. The id is of the form {letters}{numbers}, where {letters} can be 2 or 3 characters long and {numbers} can be any length. I'm trying to first grab the numbers from my id and then convert these to bigint and return this in place of the id field. My understanding for SUBSTRING is that I can use PATINDEX to get the first index where a number is encountered and grab the substring from that index. I set length to 50 only because I don't know how long a person's actual id is and 50 is the max length for [id] to begin with.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSummoner] 
    @Id varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT
        CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING([id], (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [id])), 50)) AS id
        ,[name]
        ,[modify_date]
        ,[profile_icon_id]
        ,[revision_date]
        ,[summoner_level]
    FROM [Summoners]
    WHERE [id]=@Id
END
```

**Edit:** Error message: "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Oh sorry. The error is in the title ("Error converting data type varchar to bigint.")

Comment: And would an id of `AA12345678` be an example of an @ID that produces the problem?

Comment: Yup. The first two or three characters correspond to a locale and the last digits correspond to an id. People can have the same ids, just not in the same locale. But @Zohar Peled found the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong PATINDEX. remove the `^` char.
Also, whenever you encounter problems like this the easy way to debug it is running the select without the convert and see what you get.
`CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING([id], (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [id])), 50)) As id`

Comment: Yes, this is the error. Thank you! I'm not necessarily new to SQL but PATINDEX was something new to me. I grabbed another solution from a Google search and assumed it would work in my case. My mistake!

Comment: Then please accept the answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: I cannot. There's a 15 minute grace period before I can. But I will!